# Test a Spring Boot JMS sender method with JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jms

I have a class that sends a JMS message in Spring Boot. I need to create a JUnit test to verify if the method send works well without creating a receiver in the same project. I tried different examples on the web, but most are to test the receiver method and not the sender.

```java
package example.api;

@EnableJms
@Service
public class ServiceSend {
  
  private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  public ServiceSend(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    this.jmsTemplate=jmsTemplate;
  }

  public void send(String msg) throws JMSException {

    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("myDestination", msg);
 
  }
}
```